# Sending Outlook 2013 E-Mail With Powershell, Task Scheduler (E-Mail Appears in Drafts; Doesn't Send)

Tags: powershell, email, scripting, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to send an email from my Outlook Account to my Outlook Account via Powershell and using Task Scheduler to run that script.

My Tash Scheduler is configured as such:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "<script location\script name.ps1>" -Parameter 'Value'
```

And my PowerShell script looks like:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem")
$Mail.To = "<My Email>"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject"
$Mail.Body = "Body"
$Mail.Send()
```

The e-mail gets sent successfully if I run the PS1 script myself by double clicking on it.

If I have the scheduler do it, using my account, I can see the e-mail pop into the Drafts folder of my Outlook, the Drafts folder flickers some, and the e-mail disappears.

The only thing I found when searching that it might be related to is Object Model Guard.  But I don't know how to fix that.

Any ideas on how to fix my situation?

EDIT:

I think it has to do with the setting "Run only when user is logged on" versus "Run whether user is logged on or not".

It works if I choose "Run only when user is logged on" but when I choose "Run whether user is logged on or not", it does the situation I mention above, even if I give it my password ahead of time.

Comment: Are you using outlook 2k10?

Comment: I'm using Outlook 2013

Comment: I suspect you cant run Outlook in a service mode which is why it only works when you `Run only when user is logged on`. Why do you need to use Outlook for this? Why not `Send-MailMessage`? You need to do something else if you want it to run in a service level

Comment: Matt, I tried using Send-MailMessage, but couldn't get it to work with an Outlook SMTP server.

I think I tried:

`$anonUser = "<my email>"
$anonPass = ConvertTo-SecureString "<my password>" -AsPlainText -Force

$anonCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($anonUser, $anonPass)

Send-MailMessage -To <my email> -From <my email> -Subject "Test email - PowerShell 4.0" -Body "Hello World!" -SmtpServer smtp-mail.outlook.com -Credential $anonCred`

Comment: Doesnt work isn't usually helpful debugging. Do you get any errors? This is using SMTP so you need to be allowed to do so via firewalls and appliance rules and such. If you are a 365 user? you may need to look up how to smtp to 365.

Comment: No errors.  

Email makes it into Outlook Drafts folder and then disappears.

No errors in Windows Event log view.er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

Can't believe after all of that searching and trying, I got it to work.

Having the Task Scheduler call a .BAT file that contains your PowerShell command fixed the issue, in my case:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "<script location\script name.ps1>" -Parameter 'Value'
```

No idea why this works.